# Does multi-player levelling count between games and across platforms in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Obviously you're not playing as Shephard in ME3's multi-player but as one of many other soldiers in the war. Does this mean that multiplayer levelling and progress isn't linked to any specific Shephard's carreer but will count for any Shephard on that machine?

Further, as we have to link our copies of ME3 to a Bioware/EA ID for DRM purposes, and as there will apparently be BSN (Bioware Social Network) integration (see below), does the mean that the multiplayer levelling/progress/items will count cross-platform?

[From Bioware Blog: My Interview with Mass Effect 3 Producer, Jesse Houston](http://blog.bioware.com/2011/11/04/my-interview-with-mass-effect-3-producer-jesse-houston/)

> **Will BSN track co-op statistics? ie: classes played, enemies killed,
>   wins, losses etc?**
>
> We are investigating this right now. There will
>   definitely be a lot of BSN integration. What the final list of things
>   is, we don’t really know yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that I've had a chance to play some more of the game after it was released on Friday I have some more info.

Your multi-player characters and their level/skills/abilities are stored locally, or at least they aren't synced cross-platform.

Your Galaxy At War status, however is synced up to the BioWare Social Network, and is kept in sync across platforms. You can inspect your current overall readiness and your per area readiness on the [Mass Effect 3 section](http://social.bioware.com/profile_redirect.php?game=me3) of the [Bioware Social Network](http://social.bioware.com/). Once you've logged into the BSN and [registered](http://social.bioware.com/user_bw_games_register.php) your copy of ME3 you should be able to see all of this.

You start the game with an overall readiness rating of 50%, once you start playing multi-player you start increasing the readiness scores.

I have played a small amount of multi-player on the XBox at the moment, and have an overall readiness rating of 58%. I haven't played any multi-player on the PC at all yet, and yet it also says that I have a Galactic Readiness rating of 58% on there too.

So your progress towards your Galaxy At War Galactic Readiness does sync cross platforms, and progress on one platform can help out on another.

Answer (score 2):

As far as game saves specifically they are locally stored only.  I've seen nothing to indicate cross-platform character usage.