# Does my multiplayer Galaxy at War progress count towards all my single player saves?

Tags: mass-effect-3

If I've got substantial Galaxy at War progress via the multiplayer mode, does that carry over to each different playthrough or save I might make?

For instance, right now I'm doing a Paragon run.  If I opted to restart the game with an evil Shepard, would I have to play more multiplayer on that profile/save in order to gain credit for it, or does my progress apply across all my playthroughs?

Comment: Thanks for asking this. I was wondering myself. Looking forward to having engineer Geordi La Forge as a war asset.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Galaxy At War progress is a simple multiplier that applies to all your saves, new and old. I've confirmed that my several characters all get the same Readiness bonus. after playing multiplayer.

War assets provided from promoting a Multiplayer character are different; like all war assets, they're tried to your Single player save, so if you promote a character, they won't be in your new save.

Unfortunately the [Mass Effect Wiki](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_3:_Galaxy_at_War#Galactic_Readiness) doesn't confirm this but my own playthroughs have.

Comment: Your Galaxy at War progress also counts cross-platform as well as between single-player characters (as long as you've linked them both to the same BSN account) see [Does multi-player levelling count between games and across platforms in Mass Effect 3?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/55078/263)

Answer (score 5):

The galactic readiness does not vary between single player saves, but it does decay at a rate of 1-5% a day until it reaches 50%.

Comment: confirmed btw. i had to restart my plathrough.

Comment: It has been going down way faster than 1% a day for me, I just got it to 100% yesterday, a little later it was back down to 99% then I got it back to 100%, came back the next day and it was down to 97%

Comment: actually, that started happening for me too. at the time, 1% seemed to be the average for most people